# How to write Definitions without arguments in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have the following Inductive type defined in [Coq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq).

```
Inductive natlist : Type :=
| nil : natlist
| cons : nat -> natlist -> natlist.

Notation "x :: l" := (cons x l) (at level 60, right associativity). 
Notation "[ ]" := nil.
Notation "[ x , .. , y ]" := (cons x .. (cons y  nil) ..).
```

The natlist is basically a list of natural numbers (similar to lists in Python). I am trying to find the union of two natlist using the definition below.

`Definition union_of_lists : natlist -> natlist -> natlist`

i.e 
`Eval simpl in (union_of_lists [1,2,3] [1,4,1])` 
      should return [1,2,3,1,4,1]

I have the following doubts.

- Since there are no arguments to this definition, how do I actually get the inputs and handle them?
- What does the definition union_of_lists return exactly? Is it just a natlist?

Any help or hints are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself :) What I did was, I wrote a separate Fixpoint function `append` and then assigned it to the definition of `union_of_lists`.

```
Fixpoint append(l1 l2 : natlist) : natlist :=
  match l1 with
  | nil => l2
  | (h :: t) => h :: app t l2
  end.`
```

and then

```
Definition union_of_lists : natlist -> natlist -> natlist := append.

Eval simpl in (append [1,2,3] [1,2,3]) (* returns [1,2,3,1,2,3] *)
```

The definition `union_of_lists` returns a function which takes `natlist` as an argument and returns another function of type `natlist -> natlist` (i.e function taking a `natlist` argument and returning a `natlist`).

This definition of `union_of_lists` resembles functions in [Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) which can either return a function or a value.

Comment: you could also directly have done : Fixpoint union_of_lists (l1 l2:natlist) ...., and the type would have been the same (just enter "Check append." to be sure). Or use the append List in the standard library (see http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Lists.List.html)

Comment: Yes. You are right. The types of append and union_of_lists are the same. My intention was to use the definition instead of a fixpoint. That's why I have to do that in a round about manner. Thanks for the suggestion to use standard library. I will check that out.